Creating AWS Athena Table from Pandas DataFrame
Is it possible to create a table in AWS Athena directly from a Pandas DataFrame in Python without first writing the DataFrame to an S3 bucket? If so, how can this be implemented? I'm trying to avoid storing files in S3 and would like to understand the alternative options for creating an Athena table with data from a DataFrame.
I was thinking of implementing a function like this:
def write_to_athena(df, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, region_name, database, table_name, s3_output):
"""
Writes the given DataFrame to the specified AWS Athena table.
Parameters:
    df (pd.DataFrame): The DataFrame to be written to Athena.
    aws_access_key_id (str): AWS access key ID.
    aws_secret_access_key (str): AWS secret access key.
    region_name (str): AWS region name (e.g., 'us-east-1').
    database (str): Athena database name.
    table_name (str): Table name where the data will be written.
    s3_output (str): S3 output directory for Athena query results.
"""

# Connection string for AWS Athena using credentials
conn_str = (
    f"awsathena+rest://{aws_access_key_id}:{quote_plus(aws_secret_access_key)}"
    f"@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com:443/"
    f"{database}?s3_staging_dir={quote_plus(s3_output)}&s3_dir={quote_plus(s3_output)}"
    "&compression=snappy"
)

# Create SQLAlchemy engine
engine = create_engine(conn_str)

# Write DataFrame to the specified table in Athena
df.to_sql(
    name=table_name,
    con=engine,
    schema=database,
    index=False,
    if_exists="replace",
    method="multi"
)

Is this fine or are there any issues that can raise form this?

By definition, Athena gives you data querying abilities and it runs these queries based on your dataset's meta-info/schema which it indexes in a data-catalogue. This catalogue is a central metadata repository, storing information about the location, schema, and properties of your data sources.
To work with athena, you need to offer Athena the meta-data, and the dataset. Unfortunately, I can't think of any other way to do so except by utilising an Athena compatible data source like S3, Redshift, DynamoDB, ...
